# Error in joining Separate date and time column to datetime column with NaTs in time column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

We have a date column and time column as shown below and we want a datetime column

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce').dt.date
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'] ,format='%H:%M:%S', errors = 'coerce').dt.time
df['datetime']=df['date'] + df['time']
```

However, I keep receiving the following error.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.time'
```

Comment: No. I have tried all codes in this question but nothing works. Errors received are :1) "typeerror: cannot add datetimearray and datetimearray", 2)typeerror: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'timestamp' and 'datetime.time'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'date': ['20240101', '20240102'],
        'time': ['12:00:00', '13:30:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert date and time columns to datetime objects
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce').dt.date
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce').dt.time

# Combine date and time into datetime column
df['datetime'] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.combine(row['date'], row['time']), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
         date      time            datetime
0  2024-01-01  12:00:00 2024-01-01 12:00:00
1  2024-01-02  13:30:00 2024-01-02 13:30:00
```

---

UPDATE:As per updated question to handle missing values (NaT) in your time column:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, time

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'date': ['20240101', '20240102'],
        'time': ['12:30:00', None]}  # Adding a None value to simulate missing data

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce').dt.date

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce').dt.time.fillna(time(0, 0))

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['time'].astype(str))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
         date      time            datetime
0  2024-01-01  12:30:00 2024-01-01 12:30:00
1  2024-01-02  00:00:00 2024-01-02 00:00:00
```

Comment: I received this error "TypeError: combine() argument 2 must be datetime.time, not NaTType"

Comment: It works for me with above sample data frame. That means, there are missing values (NaTType) in your 'time' column. You need to handle these missing values before combining the date and time components.

Comment: I have updated the question. Could you suggest on how do we handle NaTs?

Comment: when replaced dt.time and dt.date with dt.strftime I received this error: TypeError: combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not method

Comment: @vp_050, I have updated solution as per updated question to handle missing values (NaT) in your time column